# How to find excluded users by an exclusion script?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I would like to find users who were excluded due to the exclusion script in the email sent from the journey. I know that I can just check the data extension which was used to exclude users, but I would like to see how many of them were excluded. I do not see it anything in reports/tracking.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They’ll be in the [Not Sent](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_notsent.htm&language=en_US&type=5) data extract:

> Subscribers can be excluded from a Triggered Send using a Domain
> Exclusion Data Extensions or Exclusion Script. Excluded Subscribers
> don't appear on an Email SendLog but do appear in the NotSent Data
> Extract.

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000389503&language=en_US&type=1